# Mongoose/node.js How can i query in range [ elements between 20 and 30 ]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 500 elements in my mongodb table, I want to select for example only 100 elements after the 100 first elements. For this,  try to use `.slice` etc.. but this query doesn't work correctly. I'm using mongoose and node.js:

```
var query2 = JenkinsTestModel.find();
query2.where('jobname date').slice([-100 /*skip*/, 100 /*limit*/]) //i tried several different ways here
query2.exec(function (err, job) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(job);           
});
```

This query is returning all the elements. How do I solve the above problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the **[`skip()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip)** and the **[`limit()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit)** methods for this:

```
var query2 = JenkinsTestModel.find()
    .where('jobname date')
    .skip(100)                          
    .limit(100)   
    .exec(function (err, job) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log(job);           
    });
```

**Note**: From the **[docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.skip/)**

> The cursor.skip() method is often expensive because it requires the
>   server to walk from the beginning of the collection or index to get
>   the offset or skip position before beginning to return result. As
>   offset (e.g. pageNumber above) increases, cursor.skip() will become
>   slower and more CPU intensive. With larger collections, cursor.skip()
>   may become IO bound.